# Storing Large, Complex, Variable Object in Internal Storage in Android

Tags: android, database

I have an android app I'm working on where I want the data to be persistent. It's in a nested fashion, with the main class being an array of secondary classes, the secondary classes being an array of tertiary classes, etc., but not every array will be the same length so I can't easily write it into the columns of a SQLite database (the only form I'm familiar with) and even if they were it would be too many columns for me to fathom.

I think it would be best to store it in internal storage, and it can't be overly difficult to modify it on the fly (as the majority of the app revolves around the user modifying the arrays), but I'm fairly new to persistent data and I'm not familiar enough with data storage to figure out how to do it. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your complex object in JSON string and then store it in sharedpreferences. Whenever needed, retrieve it from SharedPreferences and re-construct complex object from JSON string. There are several libraries like `GSON` which can help you with conversion.